Why are there 2 outputs?
I am making a Wordle project. The code where it removes unnecessary items in list 'data' sometimes gives one output and sometimes gives another.
For example, if you set the 'guess' variable to 'AMPLE' (all guesses have to be in all caps) sometimes it gives:
['AI0', 'AC0', 'MI1', 'PI2', 'PC2', 'PW2', 'LI3', 'LC3', 'EI4', 'EC4']
['AI0', 'PI2', 'PW2', 'LI3', 'EI4']
['AC0', 'MI1', 'PC2', 'LC3', 'EC4']
AMPLE

and sometimes it gives:
['AC0', 'AI0', 'MI1', 'PW2', 'PI2', 'PC2', 'LI3', 'LC3', 'EI4', 'EC4']
['AI0', 'PI2', 'PI2', 'LI3', 'EI4']
['AC0', 'MI1', 'PW2', 'PC2', 'LC3', 'EC4']
AMPPLE

The part of the code where I think it breaks:
remove = []

    for x in range(len(data) - 1):
        if data[x][2] == data[x + 1][2]:
            if data[x][1] == "C":
                remove.append(str(data[x + 1]))
            elif data[x][1] == "W":
                if data[x + 1][1] == "C": 
                    remove.append(str(data[x]))
                elif data[x + 1][1] == "I": 
                    remove.append(str(data[x + 1]))
            elif data[x][1] == "I": 
                remove.append(str(data[x]))


Entire Code:
#Word and Guess
word = "APPLE"
guess = "AMPLE"

#The soon to be list of letters that will lead to the output
data = []

#Checking if guess is valid
if len(guess) != 5:
    print("Guess should be 5 letters long.")
if guess.isalpha() == False:
    print("Guess should be an English word.")
else:
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            #Adds each letter of the guess with its status and index
            #C - Correct Place, W - Wrong Place Correct Letter, I - Incorrect
            if word[x] == guess[y]:
                if x == y:
                    data.append(guess[y] + "C" + str(y))
                else:
                    data.append(guess[y] + "W" + str(y))
            else:
                data.append(guess[y] + "I" + str(y))

    #Removes duplicates
    data = set(data)
    data = list(data)          

    #Sorts based on index
    for x in range(len(data)):
        for y in range(len(data) - x - 1):
            if data[y][2] > data[y + 1][2]:
                temp = data[y]
                data[y] = data[y + 1]
                data[y + 1] = temp

    #Removes all unnecessary letters ig. removes AI0 if there is AC0
    remove = []

    for x in range(len(data) - 1):
        if data[x][2] == data[x + 1][2]:
            if data[x][1] == "C":
                remove.append(str(data[x + 1]))
            elif data[x][1] == "W":
                if data[x + 1][1] == "C": 
                    remove.append(str(data[x]))
                elif data[x + 1][1] == "I": 
                    remove.append(str(data[x + 1]))
            elif data[x][1] == "I": 
                remove.append(str(data[x]))

    oL = [x for x in data if x not in remove]

    #Makes output have colorful letters for convenience 
    output = ""

    for x in range(len(oL)):
        if oL[x][1] == "C":
            output = output + "\033[1;33;40m" + oL[x][0]
        elif oL[x][1] == "W":
            output = output + "\033[1;32;40m" + oL[x][0]
        elif oL[x][1] == "I":
            output = output + "\033[1;37;40m" + oL[x][0]
    output = output + "\033[0;37;40m"

#Tests
print(data)
print(remove)
print(oL)

#Output
print(output)

I have tried changing that part of the code, but to no avail. I believe the problem is in that specific line of code or how sets work as they are unordered. I am sorry if the answer is pretty obvious as I am not that great at Python. I hope there is a solution to this problem.

Don't repeat yourself but we do appreciate a [mre].

In general change your comments to the name of a function.  It is better documentation and it's easier to reason about your code when everything isn't global variables.

Why is it a "problem" to get different outputs?

I do believe the problem you are encountering has to do with converting to a set and then back into a list.  It may be better to avoid having duplicates in the first place by changing up your flow of logic.  Here's a version that works and avoids duplicating:
def check_letter(index, word, guess):
    letter = guess[index]

    # check letter in word
    if not letter in word:
        # return incorrect result
        return f'{letter}I{index}'
    # letter is in word; check position
    if letter == word[index]:  # positions match
        # return correct result
        return f'{letter}C{index}'
    else:
        # return correct letter, wrong position
        return f'{letter}W{index}'

def main():
    word = "APPLE"
    guess = input("Enter guess: ")

    while len(guess) != 5 or not guess.isalpha():
        print("Please enter a five-letter guess.")
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")

    guess = guess.upper()  # ensure capital letters

    results = []  # to be populated

    # check each letter
    for index in range(0, 5):
        results.append(check_letter(index, word, guess))

    print(results)

# Run the script
main()


This accomplishes your desired output but is a bit cleaner.  If you're unfamiliar with any concepts used here, feel free to comment, I'm happy to clarify this code and my thinking in writing it!


Instead of converting data to a set to remove duplicates, use a
different approach that maintains the order.
You can iterate through the list and build a new list that only includes unique elements while preserving the original order.

#Word and Guess
word = "APPLE"
guess = "AMPLE"

#The soon to be list of letters that will lead to the output
data = []

#Checking if guess is valid
if len(guess) != 5:
    print("Guess should be 5 letters long.")
if not guess.isalpha():
    print("Guess should be an English word.")
else:
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            #Adds each letter of the guess with its status and index
            #C - Correct Place, W - Wrong Place Correct Letter, I - Incorrect
            if word[x] == guess[y]:
                if x == y:
                    data.append(guess[y] + "C" + str(y))
                else:
                    data.append(guess[y] + "W" + str(y))
            else:
                data.append(guess[y] + "I" + str(y))

    # Remove duplicates while preserving order
    seen = set()
    unique_data = []
    for item in data:
        if item not in seen:
            unique_data.append(item)
            seen.add(item)
    data = unique_data

    # Sorts based on index
    for x in range(len(data)):
        for y in range(len(data) - x - 1):
            if data[y][2] > data[y + 1][2]:
                temp = data[y]
                data[y] = data[y + 1]
                data[y + 1] = temp

    # Removes all unnecessary letters, e.g., removes AI0 if there is AC0
    remove = []

    for x in range(len(data) - 1):
        if data[x][2] == data[x + 1][2]:
            if data[x][1] == "C":
                remove.append(str(data[x + 1]))
            elif data[x][1] == "W":
                if data[x + 1][1] == "C": 
                    remove.append(str(data[x]))
                elif data[x + 1][1] == "I": 
                    remove.append(str(data[x + 1]))
            elif data[x][1] == "I": 
                remove.append(str(data[x]))

    oL = [x for x in data if x not in remove]

    # Makes output have colorful letters for convenience 
    output = ""

    for x in range(len(oL)):
        if oL[x][1] == "C":
            output = output + "\033[1;33;40m" + oL[x][0]
        elif oL[x][1] == "W":
            output = output + "\033[1;32;40m" + oL[x][0]
        elif oL[x][1] == "I":
            output = output + "\033[1;37;40m" + oL[x][0]
    output = output + "\033[0;37;40m"

# Tests
print(data)
print(remove)
print(oL)

# Output
print(output)

This approach ensures that duplicates are removed while maintaining the original order of elements, so your outputs should be consistent.
